# Как получить разность дат?

Tags: javascript, jquery

если есть даты в формате переменных

let **var1** = 04.12.21
и **var2** = 14.12.21

и строка
let **str** = 04.12.21 - 14.12.21

21 это год

можно получить разность дат в обеих случаях?

Comment: Какой формат ответа предполагается?

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian , в данном случае 10

Comment: а если больше месяца разница, тоже в днях? То есть просто посчитать сколько дней разница?

Comment: да. именно дни нужны

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так сделать

```js
function formdat(d){  
  return '20' + d.split('.').reverse().join('-');
}
var date2 = new Date(formdat("04.12.21"));
var date1 = new Date(formdat("14.12.21"));

function calcDate(date1,date2) {
    var diff = Math.floor(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
    var day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var days = Math.floor(diff/day);
    var months = Math.floor(days/31);
    var years = Math.floor(months/12);

    var message = date2.toDateString();
    message += " was "
    message += days + " days " 
    message += months + " months "
    message += years + " years ago \n"

    return message
    }


a = calcDate(date1,date2)
console.log(a)
```

Comment: @PavelNazarian почему?)

Comment: @PavelNazarian а "-" где не проходит?)) Не должен быть?

Comment: @ Rudi , спасибо. а если будет формат 04.12.2021 - не пройдет?

Comment: Заменить полностью функцию `function formdat(d)...` на `function formdat(d){  
  let dt = d.split('.');
  return dt[dt.length-1].length>2 ? dt = dt.reverse().join('-') : dt = '20' + d.split('.').reverse().join('-'); 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал не изобретать велосипеды а использовать moment

```js
const date1 = moment('04.12.21', 'DD.MM.YY');
const date2 = moment('14.12.21', 'DD.MM.YY');

const diff = date1.diff(date2, 'days');
console.log(diff) // -10
```

Comment: что за moment??

Comment: @Air библиотека.. Из недостатков упоминается относительно большой размер библиотеки (329KB без сжатия, 70КБ со сжатием) Находится в режиме сопровождения, подразумевающем остановку расширения функциональности, заморозку API и ограничение активности исправлением серьёзных ошибок. Для новых проектов Moment.js применять не рекомендуется. 16 сентября 2020 года