# Написать функцию, которая на вход берет две даты и возвращает количество полных дней между ними

Tags: javascript

Как написать функцию, которая берет две даты и возвращает количество полных дней между ними? Вроде написал но не все тесты проходит.

Вот мой код:

```
function getDaysBetweenDates(first, second) {
    let date1 = new Date(first);
    let date2 = new Date(second);
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
      throw new TypeError("TypeError");
    } else {
      let oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
      let time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
      let days = 0;
      if (time < 0) {
        days === 0;
      } else {
        days = Math.trunc(time / oneDay);
      }
      return days;
    }
  }
```

а вот тесты который он должен проходит:

```
Ваш ответ не прошел тест!
FAIL test.js
  валидные данные
    ✓ возвращает количество полных дней между датами (4ms)
    ✕ возвращает отрицательное число, если первая дата больше второй (3ms)
    ✓ обработка дат в миллисекундах getDaysBetweenDates(1409796000000, 1409925600000) (1ms)
    ✓ обработка дат в виде текста getDaysBetweenDates('1-1-2020', '1-3-2020')
  невалидные данные
    ✓ возвращает NaN, если первая дата Invalid date (1ms)
    ✓ возвращает NaN, если вторая дата Invalid date (5ms)
    ✓ возвращает NaN, если обе даты Invalid date
    ✓ проброс исключения TypeError , если передано менее 2-х аргументов (2ms)
  крайние случаи
    ✓ разница между датами меньше дня, но первая дата меньше второй (1ms)
    ✓ разница между датами меньше дня, но первая дата больше второй
    ✓ разница между датами ровно 24 часа
    ✓ даты равны между собой
    ✓ одна из дат равна null
```

✕ возвращает отрицательное число, если первая дата больше второй (3ms),
Ведь метод и так то должен же возвращать отрицательно число?

Comment: Задание требует КОЛИЧЕСТВО. Которое по определению неотрицательно. Про направление в задании ни полслова нет.

Comment: @Akina Самого напрягает когда обламываешься не на решении самой задачи (причём решение в голове есть сходу), а на не полном описании. Узнаешь непосредсвенно с тестов что надо делать)

Comment: Посмотри [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1357247/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82/1357253#1357253) может подойдёт, по условиям доработаешь..

Comment: Немножко изменил:
```
function getDaysBetweenDates(first, second) {
    let date1 = new Date(first);
    let date2 = new Date(second);
    if (arguments.length < 2) {
      throw new TypeError("TypeError");
    } else {
      let oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
      let time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
      let days = Math.trunc(time / oneDay);
      return days;
    }
}
```
но в этом случает не проходит тест на: ✕ разница между датами меньше дня, но первая дата больше второй (4ms)